# SHA 256 of what?

Tags: python, request, sha256

https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html

I have been trying to code a trading bot. I have figured out the data and decision making part of the program. Now I need to code the making order part of the program.

I checked their website and found that I need to supply the sha256 of

> clientsecret|totalparams

and that

> totalParams is defined as the query string concatenated with the request body

So far this is what I have:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': MY_API_KEY,
}

data = [
  ('symbol', 'LTCBTC'),
  ('side', 'BUY'),
  ('type', 'LIMIT'),
  ('timeInForce', 'GTC'),
  ('quantity', '1'),
  ('price', '0.1'),
  ('recvWindow', '6000000'),
  ('timestamp', '1499827319559'),
  ('signature', NO_IDEA ),
]

requests.post('https://www.binance.com/api/v1/order', headers=headers, data=data)
```

I need to figure out what the signature and by extension totalparams would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation just wants you to use the request body, the query string on the url, and the client secret together in one string (the query string and request body are concatenated together, and then the client secret is prepended with a `|` character).

You can use a [prepared request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests); this gives you access to the query string and request body *before sending*:

```
import requests
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def calculate_signature(secret, data=None, params=None):
    # the actual URL doesn't matter as this request is never sent.
    request = requests.Request('POST', 'http://example.com',
                               data=data, params=params)
    prepped = request.prepare()
    query_string = urlparse(prepped.url).query
    # neither the URL nor the body are encoded to bytes yet
    total_params = query_string + prepped.body
    return hashlib.sha256('{}|{}'.format(secret, total_params).encode('ASCII')).hexdigest()

MY_API_KEY = 'XXX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXX'

headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': MY_API_KEY,
}

data = [
  ('symbol', 'LTCBTC'),
  ('side', 'BUY'),
  ('type', 'LIMIT'),
  ('timeInForce', 'GTC'),
  ('quantity', '1'),
  ('price', '0.1'),
  ('recvWindow', '6000000'),
  ('timestamp', '1499827319559'),
]

data.append(
    ('signature', calculate_signature(CLIENT_SECRET, data=data)))

response = requests.post('https://www.binance.com/api/v1/order', data=data, headers=headers)
```

The prepared request object was only used to give you the request body to sign. Their API is a little convoluted in that they then expect you to append the signature to the request body itself rather than in a header (which is what most REST APIs do).

The `calculate_signature()` function produces the same results as the documentation:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
>>> documentation_secret = 'NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j'
>>> requestBody = parse_qsl('symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=6000000&timestamp=1499827319559')
>>> calculate_signature(documentation_secret, requestBody)
'24b39c6588d0f2378a2b641e68c00e87bc81d997146ca3c5482337857a045041'
>>> queryString = parse_qsl('symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC')
>>> requestBody = parse_qsl('quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=6000000&timestamp=1499827319559')
>>> calculate_signature(documentation_secret, requestBody, queryString)
'77eb3b3727bc8c523646e2a35f52a8eb4cc4418b24c113f3ea0b3b59248579d4'
```

Answer (score 0):

`hashlib` provides various hash function including `sha256`, e.g.:

```
 import hashlib
 hashlib.sha256('|'.join([clientsecret, totalparams]).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: I meant to ask what totalparams would be as well. Editing the post now.

Comment: See @MartijnPieters post. You need to pass in the query parameters + request body. You can use `requests` or `urllib.parse` to split a url into it's parts.

Comment: Ok. Looking into it.

Comment: No worries, I have no issues people voting down, would be great to get feedback only for improvement purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152906/discussion-between-rjpj1998-and-achampion).

Comment: Perhaps your answer didn't address the question? The OP was asking what needed signing, not how to sign. *I need to figure out what [...] totalparams would be*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps, but the OP updated that part of his question after my answer. And by that time you were well head of answering the totality of the OPs question, no need for me to duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

from the page you linked there is example of how to calculate it:

```
echo -n "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j|symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=6000000&timestamp=1499827319559" | sha256sum
24b39c6588d0f2378a2b641e68c00e87bc81d997146ca3c5482337857a045041  -
```

simple function to calculate the sig without too many requests manipulations (because we know data is list of tuples it will be ordered and passed down correctly, if it was dict it might not preserve the order)

```
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import urlencode
data = [...]  # your params

def calc_sig(data, your_secret_key):
    sig_content = '%s|%s' % (your_secret_key, urlencode(data))
    return hashlib.sha256(sig_content).hexdigest()
```